# Does having your domain and web host at the same company reduce DNS propagation times?

Tags: dns, migration

My domain is registered at HostGator (aka LaunchPad.com), and my web host is GoDaddy. During my set up at GoDaddy, it said that my domain wasn't hosted with them, and that it could slow DNS propagation having it elsewhere, and that I should pay to migrate my domain over to them.

Could there really be benefits like this to having a domain registered and hosted at the same company?

Comment: Often when you register a domain for the first time and depending on the registrar they may use their name servers upon registering it, and technically if you change DNS after its been registered you need to wait, however if your able to change the DNS during registration, not after... there would be the same propagation times

Comment: Nope, generally there isn't...

Comment: "I should pay to migrate my domain over to them" - Apart from possibly paying for an _additional_ years registration, you wouldn't necessarily expect to have to pay for a domain migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Propagation times are controlled by the [time to live (TTL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live#DNS_records) that is set on the DNS record.   The only way to get DNS changes live faster is to have a shorter TTL specified.

GoDaddy may be offering to set a short TTL for you, but there is no reason that a short TTL can't be specified at most DNS hosts.

Default TTL values vary widely between DNS hosts.   Some may use 30 minute TTLs, but most set 12 hour, 24 hour, 48 hour, or even 36 hour TTLs.

Short TTLs may not even be honored by many caching DNS servers and they may cache records longer than indicated when they deem TTL values to small.   Regardless of what your TTL is set to, you should plan to have you old server running for three days after you switch the DNS records.   95% of your traffic should move over within the TTL expiry, but a small amount may hit the old server for days.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**.

Whether or not you have your DNS hosted at your registrar **has no bearing whatsoever** on how quickly DNS changes propagate. This is classic GoDaddy marketing BS.

The only factor under your control that affects propagation time is the DNS records' TTL. The TTL settings available to you depend solely on your DNS provider, not your registrar.

<sup>As a side note, the term "dns propagation" [is a bit of a misnomer](https://support.cozaq.com/hc/en-us/articles/360014905473-What-is-DNS-Propagation-), but it conveys the process well enough.</sup>